# vs2013 rc open projects created by vs2013 stardard

Tags: visual-studio-2013

As the title!
Can visual-studio-2013 RC open projects created by visual-studio-2013 standard edition?
I have created projects by visual-studio-2013 standard edition.
Then someone still used the RC.
Is there any troubles?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an expired beta version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general IDEs are backwardly compatible in that they can open projects created by (at least the last few) older versions of themselves. They have no knowledge of newer versions though so you are always taking a risk when you try and open a newer project with older software.